# ¿Cómo separar miles de un número en SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

Estoy realizando un `query`, donde los resultados que me devuelve son números muy grandes y se dificulta la lectura del monto si no están los puntos para separar las unidades de los números, me gustaría saber si existe la posibilidad de realizar esto en `SQL`.

Este es el `query` que tengo:

```
   select
        banco                    as BANCO,
        sum(TDA)                 as ACTIVOS,
        sum(CV+CR+CVNCD+CEL)     as CARTERA,
        sum(ITV)                 as ITV,
        sum(CDP)                 as CAPTACIONES,
        sum(TDP)                 as PASIVOS,
        sum(TPT)                 as PATRIMONIO,
        sum(BOIFP+BCE+ITV+CV+CR) as ACTIVOS_R
    from RR001 
    where fecha between to_date('2017/12/01','YYYY/MM/DD') and  to_date('2018/01/01','YYYY/MM/DD') 
    group by banco
```

Los resultados que me arroja son los siguientes: 
[image: QUERY]

Me gustaría saber si es posible de alguna manera que los resutados salgan de la siguiente manera por ejemplo:

```
1.718.062,82
459.316,79
```

Y si es posible hacerlo,¿cómo sería?, gracias de antemano.

Comment: La forma en que se representa el dato depende de las posibilidades de configuración de la herramienta con la que visualizas la consulta ¿Que usas?.Sino, puedes convertir los números en cadenas y formatearlos, pero claro, pierdes la naturaleza del dato numérico, además que seguramente el dato se verá alineado a izquierda

Comment: Utilizo oracle sql developer, pero la verdad no tengo idea de cómo está configurado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para dar formato de moneda a algo, puedes usar

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(10000,'L99G999D99MI',
               'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''
               NLS_CURRENCY = ''$''') "Amount"
           FROM DUAL;
```

Lo que en este ejemplo mostraría `$10,000.00`. Sólo reemplazas el primer parámetro de TO_CHAR por la columna cuyos datos deseas presentar con formato y debería funcionar.

- Referencia en SO original: [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25545224/236345)
- Documentación Oracle: [enlace](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm)

Comment: Excelente, funciona perfecto muchas gracias